# preg_replace replace a prefix with a suffix plus itself

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a list of mobile phone `$numbers` and i have to change them, prefixing the number `39`, if the number itself starts with one in `$prefixes` array.

I don't now how to **back referencing to the found prefix**, or (it's the same) how to get the matched prefix). I've tried the following but it's not working:

```
$numbers  = array('3284121532', '3478795687'); // the subject
$prefixes = array('328', '347');               // (will be) the pattern

// Build regex for each element of $prefix array
$pattern = array_map(function($s) { return "/^$s/"; }, $prefixes);
$replace = "39\{$1}";

var_dump(preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $numbers);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're not using `preg_replace` anywhere in your code.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen sorry, fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$numbers  = array(3284121532, 3478795687);
$prefixes = implode('|',array(328, 347));

$numbers = array_map(function($n) use ($prefixes) {
    return preg_replace("/^($prefixes)/", '39$1', $n);
}, $numbers);

print_r($numbers);
```

The above will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 393284121532
    [1] => 393478795687
)
```

Comment: `$prefixes` array is dynamic, why in preg_replace you are using `328|347`?

Comment: Thanks, works, i've slightly adapted your solution. Essentially my mistake was not adding the (group, i suppose) and using `{}` around the reference. Thanks again.

Comment: It is pointless to remove and then replace the trailing part of the string. `preg_replace("/^($prefixes)/", '39$1', $n)` is fine.

Comment: Ignore. Answer had changed before I finished writing comment. No delete option on mobile!

Comment: What's the point of `$2`? your regex is `39$1$2` that's pointless

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the whole match in your replacement, you can use `$0`:

```
$replace = '39$0';
```

Comment: Awesome! you just helped me out of a bind Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Just use `$1` within single quote.

```
$replace = '39$1;
```

You can do that with

```
$results = array_map(function($s) { 
    return preg_replace("/^(".join('|' . $prefixes) . "\d+)/", '39$1', $s); 
}, $numbers );
```

Comment: I am not sure why it has downvotes. seems like legit solution.